# Convert.ToBase64String return same value for codeBarre in RDLC REPORT .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, rdlc

I have a rdlc report return a pdf. The pdf  has tickets, each ticket has information name, Date_Creation, CodeBarre...
The codeBarre is image when I convert the path of image To `Base64String` the same value affected for all ticket but in the database is different codebarre and path for each ticket.

The result is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OZPA.png)

The problem is here I received the same result for all item

```
result = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
```

The code for Generate pdf with tickets is:

```cs
public DataTable GeneratePdfWithTickets(string user, int id)
{
    var Bonsrecherche = _BonsLivraison.Get(id, user);
    IEnumerable<Colis> colisrecherche = _Colis.ColisWithBonsId(user, id);

    // Create a new DataTable to hold ticket data
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    //dt.Columns.Add("Prix");

    //dt.Columns.Add("Phone");
    //dt.Columns.Add("Adresse");
    //dt.Columns.Add("Nom_Complet");
    //dt.Columns.Add("Ville");
    //dt.Columns.Add("Boutique");
    //dt.Columns.Add("USERNAME");
    //dt.Columns.Add("PhoneUser");
    dt.Columns.Add("CodeBarre");

    // Generate tickets for each colis
    foreach (var item in colisrecherche)
    {
        // Create a new row for each ticket
        DataRow Row = dt.NewRow();
      
        Row["Name"] = item.Numero_Colis;
   
        string relativeImagePath = item.CodeBarre.Chemin.ToString().TrimStart('/');
        string webRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        string absoluteImagePath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, relativeImagePath);

        string result = null; 
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(absoluteImagePath))
        {
            byte[] imageData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(absoluteImagePath);
            result = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData); // the probleme is here i received the same result for all item
        
        }
        Row["CodeBarre"] = result;

        dt.Rows.Add(Row);
    }

    return dt;
}

// code for action in controller
public async Task<IActionResult> stickers(int id)
{
    string user = await Returnuser();
    var Bonsrecherche = _BonsLivraison.Get(id, user);

    IEnumerable<Colis> colisrecherche = _Colis.ColisWithBonsId(user, id);

    if (Bonsrecherche is null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("index");

    }

    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt = GeneratePdfWithTickets(user, id);
    string mimetype = "";
    int extension = 1;
    var path = $"{this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\Reports\\Sticker.rdlc";
    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport(path);
  
    localReport.AddDataSource("dsSticker", dt);
    var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, parameters, mimetype);
    return File(result.MainStream, " application/pdf");
}
```

Can anyone tell me why Convert.ToBase64String return same value for all codeBarre ?

Comment: Are you sure the paths or images are different? If you load the same bytes, the BASE64 string will be the same as well

Comment: Could it be that the three bar codes are indeed identical?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes  the path is different 
i can see the barcode in HTML for each ticket each ticket has different barcode Image
and also the database has different value for Path

Comment: the path is correct you can see the database here : https://pasteboard.co/76UlacX7eMdS.png

Comment: @KlausGütter Maybe

Comment: On the picture you posted, the three bar codes are exactly identical.

Comment: I can't see anything in *the code itself* and screenshots can't prove that you found a bug nobody else has encountered in 23 years. Are you sure the *report* is correct? How did you determine the `result` string is the same? Post actual executable code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Actual executable code means creating two `byte[]` arrays with different data that result in identical results from `ToBase64String`. That should only take 5 lines, apart from the data itself. 2 lines to create the arrays, 2 to calculate the strings, 1 `Debug.Assert(result1!=result2)` that fails because the strings are identical

Comment: Are you sure the *report* is correct? Perhaps the image wasn't created in the detail row? Or it binds to the first row only?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have made a breakpoint in the code this is what i received in each row ticket 1 :https://pasteboard.co/ySBt6YxIe8gV.png
row ticket 2 :https://pasteboard.co/mevY3xKntUUY.png
row ticket 3 :https://pasteboard.co/UwEGjD0gQf3t.png

Comment: The original image shows identical barcodes. Your very own question shows that the barcodes are identical. The new images prove *nothing* - the headers of image formats can be identical. Especially when they contain so similar data. Entire regions with the same white color.  It's the entire string that needs checking. Again, are you sure your report isn't wrong? You can't claim you're the only developer in 23 years to find a problem in functions used by everyone and every single ASP.NET site.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in this case What will i do now ?